# Conventional unit mesh

Tags: image-processing, symmetry, tiling

[image]

I'm trying to find and outline a non-primitive conventional unit mesh, I'm not sure how to go about it.
I'd also like to find any mirrors of planes and rotional symmetry axes.

Would this look correc for a conventional unit mesh that is non-primitive?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would certainly be able to replicate the matrix outwards, but isn't it better to find the smallest tile? There is a whole one inside the area you selected. Both are hexagonal units with mirror and rotational symmetry of 60°.

Added:
What about this one?
[image]

Comment: ah the one inside it, that should work as well since it wouldn't be primitive still,
i'd upvote but i have to be lvl 15

Comment: @user45468 You can always accept an answer as the best answer to your question. Since very few people have have a change to see this question, you may want to wait a day before accepting an answer.

Comment: just did, also if i were to mark all mirror planes and rotational symmetry, would it look something like this? https://imgur.com/Bkjwhih

Comment: The unit you selected in the link will not replicate the pattern properly. The unit cell is larger. Yes, the mirror planes and rotational axises are correct.

Comment: the only other structure i found was this but that can't be right since it doesn't match the primitive hexagon https://imgur.com/ApIAb6b

Comment: @user45468 How about rotating the hexagon 30° about the center. It's about the right size.

Comment: hmm, i'm not seeing it, even when i rotate it around 30-45 degrees i don't see which points it would line up with that would match

i'm also starting to doubt the symettry I drew because I think for hexagonal there should be 6 lines on the top half, not 4. i'll double check

Comment: doesn't the outer end points have to match the inside symmetry? Because those circles have 9 points, while the inner pattern has 6 verticles. either way, you have helped so much

you don' have to get back ot this but i'll ask anyway
https://imgur.com/GopAzmM
this is also hexagonal, but notice how the axis of symmetry there are 8 lines on the top rather than 6. 
i'm not sure if that applies here